# SharpJS pipe memory leak on linux

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, fs, sharp

I'm reading from a fs `readStream` (from graphql upload file) and piping it through SharpJS transform function and piping it through a `writeStream` to write to a file.
In my system (windows) it works just fine but in my Host (linux) it creates a core dump file with 500mb size and the images that it creates are with size of 0 kb.

```
     const transform = (dimen) => sharp().resize(dimen, dimen)
        const fs512 = fs.createWriteStream(addSuffix(filePath))
        const fs256 = fs.createWriteStream(addSuffix(filePath))
        const fs128 = fs.createWriteStream(addSuffix(filePath))

        await stream.pipe(transform(512)).pipe(fs512)
        await stream.pipe(transform(256)).pipe(fs256)
        await stream.pipe(transform(128)).pipe(fs128)
```

I have tried listening on `finish` event and closing them but it didn't work.
**I think the issue is because of SharpJS**, if I remove the first pipe, it works (without resizing).

Comment: I gave up, stopped using sharp and used Jimp